# Elliptic Curve Point Addition; two possible Lambda Solutions?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elliptic-curves, cryptography

I'm trying to double the Point $P(1,17)$ on the Elliptic Curve $y^2 = x^3 + 3x + 6 \pmod {31}$.

I'm using the formulae:
$$\begin{split}
λ&=(3xp^2+a)(2yp)^{-1}\\
xr &= λ^2 - 2xp\\
yr &= λ(xp-xr)-yp
\end{split}$$

I get $λ = 29$, $xr = 2$, $yr = 16 \implies 2P = (2,16)$.
However, according to an online calculator, the solution should be $2P = (2,12)$.
If I use $-λ$ instead of $λ$ while calculating $yr$, I get the right result, but if I then try to double again to $4P$ it only works with $λ$.

What am I not getting here?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I don’t think $(2,16)$ is a point on the curve…

Comment: So was my formula for λ incorrect? Or should I try λ and -λ each time and check if one option is not on the curve?

Comment: And if so, are there cases where both options are on the curve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula is correct, compare with [point doubling formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_point_multiplication#Point_doubling).
I will use $m$ instead of $\lambda$ for the slope, simpler to type.
Let us do the computations explicitly:

The values for $a,b$ are $3,6$, we are working over the field $\Bbb F_p$ with
$p=31$ elements, and consider the given curve $y^2 =x^3 +ax+b$. Then for $P=(x_P,y_P)=(1,17)\in E(F)$ we have the computation of $R=2P$ in $F$...
$$
\begin{aligned}
m &=\frac{3x_P^2+a}{2y_p}=\frac{3\cdot 1^2+3}{2\cdot 17}
=6\cdot 2^{-1}\cdot17^{-1}=6\cdot16\cdot 11=96\cdot 11=3\cdot 11=33
\\
&=\bbox[yellow]{\boxed{2}}\ ,
\\
x_R &=m^2-2x_P=2^2-2\cdot 1=\bbox[yellow]{\boxed{2}}\ ,\\
y_R &=m(x_P-x_R)-y_P=2(1-2)-17=-2-17=-19=\bbox[yellow]{\boxed{12}}\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
Please compare with your own computation.

---

Computer check, here using [sage](https://www.sagemath.org):

```
sage: E = EllipticCurve(GF(31), (3, 6))
sage: E
Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 = x^3 + 3*x + 6 over Finite Field of size 31
sage: P = E.point( (1, 17) )
sage: 2*P
(2 : 12 : 1)
sage: (2*P).xy()
(2, 12)
```

Comment: I computed m like this: $$ \frac{3\cdot 1^{2}+3}{2\cdot17}= \frac{6}{34}=\frac{6}{3}=6\cdot3^{-1}=6\cdot10 =29 $$ While writing this reply, I realised that over the course of losing my sanity and during 3 hours of headscratching I used 10 instead of -10 = 21 as the inverse of 3. Im sorry I wasted your time for this, and thanks for your help :)

Comment: No problem, please always ask, if you work on a detail, and the error does not show up even after checking it some more times, just ask, do not hesitate, you need one more pair of eyes!